# How to fetch an image from server URL data to UIBarButton?

Tags: swift, uiimageview, uibarbuttonitem

I want to fetch an image from server URL in to my bar button item. I am using code like below but it is gives an error : Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value . how can I solve this problem ? Note: loadImg func is an extension and its working another controller. and serverURL is my class for profile data.

```swift
let imageView = UIImageView()
imageView.loadImg(url: URL(string: self.serverURL.ppUrl!)!) // this line give error
let customView = UIButton(type: .system)
customView.setImage(imageView.image, for: .normal)
customView.backgroundColor = .white

let barButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: customView)
navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = barButtonItem

extension UIImageView {
    public func loadImg(url: URL) {
        DispatchQueue.global().async { [weak self] in
            if let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url) {
                if let image = UIImage(data: data) {

                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self?.image = image
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are force unwrapping two optionals (marked with the `!`). If one or both of them are nil, you will get a crash.  So you need to check first if they exist, and bail otherwise.

Something like this:

```
let imageView = UIImageView()
if let urlString = self.serverURL.ppUrl as? String, let url = URL(string: urlString) as? URL {

    imageView.loadImg(url: url)
    ...
}
```

Comment: thank you I tried it but still same error. I will check my data

Comment: You can find more info about this error here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32170456/what-does-fatal-error-unexpectedly-found-nil-while-unwrapping-an-optional-valu

Comment: And what is `loadImg` ?

Comment: loadImg is an extension for fetch image like url string from server data. it is working in other controllers. And in this controllers I  use two optionals (marked with !) but it is working.

Comment: and "if let " modality,  safety than my "unwrapping two optionals" its it right ? I am new with swift programming

Comment: Please add the code for `loadImg` to your question. Crash could occur there as well. The fact you don't have the crash in other cases only means that your optionals are not nil.

Comment: I added it loadImg func

Comment: I added some updates to my answer, can you try now? I don't see anything suspicious in `imgLoad`.

Comment: Still same error.  I making  a mistake somewhere but I don't know. May is relative about bar button item ?   Should I try with "didSet" method what you think ?

Comment: What line do you get the error now? Are you 200% sure that `self.serverURL.ppUrl` is a string?

Comment: Yes exactly that line